# Clear cookies on browser close

Tags: cookies, browser

How to clear the cookies that has been stored through my asp.net mvc(C#) application, when the user closes the browser?

Is there any option to create a cookie such that it expires once the browser closed?

I need to use cookies, because i will store some of the values to be maintained until the browser is closed.

For example, During sign in i may store the userid in cookie, which i can use for my application processes till the bwoser closes.

Session will expire after some particular time, which i need to overcome with using cookies

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sessions are usualy used for this. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation), when no expiration date is set, a cookie is cleared when the user closes the browser.

> The cookie setter can specify a deletion date, in which case the cookie will be removed on that date. If the cookie setter does not specify a date, the cookie is removed once the user quits his or her browser.

Comment: The session will expire when the user keeps the browser open for long time. Will the cookie with no expiry date lasts until the browser closes?

Comment: It really depends on how the browser has implemented it.

Comment: You cannot count on the cookie being deleted when the browser closes.

Comment: To expand on @ChrisHanson 's comment, some browser - e.g. Google Chrome - no longer respect the session cookie 'standard' - i.e. a session cookie is no longer removed when the browser is closed. From what I can tell, a session cookie now lasts indefinitely.

Comment: Certainly when there are multiple browser windows, they seem to keep a handle to the session cookie... requiring all browser instances to close before it is removed.  Trying to find documentation on this is hard.

Comment: Depends on setting the cookie get removed see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies

Comment: Since 2012 or earlier, Chrome, Firefox, and possibly other browsers do not actually delete session cookies when closing all windows and/or quitting the browser, so this answer doesn't really work at all in the real world anymore and is now dangerously misleading.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this SO question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347227/how-to-make-an-asp-net-session-cookie-expire-with-the-asp-net-httpsession)

```
Response.Cookies("cookie_name").Expires = Session.Timeout;
```

Comment: You actually want to specify no Expires value on the cookie.  This will cause the cookie to be removed when the browser session ends (user closes the browser).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script and call it in the body tag

```
<body onunload="dc()">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function dc(){
    document.cookie = 'access=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

When I set my cookie to expire in the past or did not set it at all, it caused by SSO login to get into an infinite loop with my site. Probably I configured my site wrong to work with the SSO login.

But what worked for me was just adding 2 seconds to the cookie expiration time.

```
trackCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2);
```

This gives the cookie the validity on login. And expires it soon after. So on close of the browser, the cookie is deleted.