# How do I remove cookies when the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clear cookies on browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close)

When I close the browser, I want to remove cookies. How can I do this?

Comment: I think if you set the expiration date to one in the past, the cookies will be deleted once you close the browser.

Comment: Have you thought of using a session cookie instead that automatically expires when the browser is closed?

Comment: Please clarify your question. By "I" do you mean the user or the programmer? Either one can remove cookies when the browser closes.

Answer (score 48):

If you don't set an expiry date it defaults to expire at the end of the session . Refer this links -

[jscookies](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/js/jscookies.html)

Comment: +1 for the real way to do it ;)

Comment: Sorry, can you update the link? it's broken now...

Comment: Suppose I do close the browser but just close that particular browser "tab", will the cookie for the application of that tab be deleted? Will this behavior be browser specific?

Comment: @hagrawal when you close the tab, it will close the session and the session cookie will be removed from browser memory.

Comment: @JacobRossDev Closing the browser tab will not clear the session cookie, it will only be cleared when browser is closed.

Comment: @hagrawal you're right. when I tested this it worked as I described but this wasn't consistent thru more testing.

Comment: The link is not accessible now!

Comment: @Tejus Prasad Please update the link, its broken.

Answer (score 7):

taken from [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldelck.htm)

```
function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name +
    '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
```

Now all you need to do is to call this `del_cookie()` function passing it the name of whatever cookie it is that we wish to delete. The function will update the expiry date on the cookie to one long in the past so that the cookie will be considered to be expired and will be ignored by the browser exactly the same as if it didn't exist

to be used something like

```
<body onload="SetCookie()" onunload="del_cookie()">
```

Comment: you can call this function on "onunload" browser event, and it will detect browser close event and call the function.

Comment: @God it will also be called every page refresh, hopefully that won't ruin the OP plans..

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [session cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie).

A tutorial on hwo to create them in JavaScript is available [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookie.shtml).