# Browser Close and Tab Close Identifier

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I want need a way to identify the when a user is closing a tab or closing a browser.

The behavior I am expecting for user is to end his session only on browser close and not on tab close.

I have tried following the below stackoverflow trail:-

[detect-browser-or-tab-closing--stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

But all the solution pinning towards restricting browser reload.

Any strategic and technical help would be apreciated.

Comment: This already has an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4985724/4244684

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove cookies when the browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985693/how-do-i-remove-cookies-when-the-browser-is-closed)

Comment: basically If you don't set an expiry date it defaults to expire at the end of the session . - Sessions only end, when browser is closed - not on tab close

Comment: session cookie will solve the problem...but is their any side effect to pushing cookie strategy in production?