# wordpress remove cookies after browser closed

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

i just want to remove my wordpress cookie after browser tab closed ,

in pluggable.php FILE line 653 :

if ( $remember ) {
    $expiration = $expire = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 1209600, $user_id, $remember);
} else {
    $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 500,  $user_id, $remember);
     $expire = 0;

i change every thing i could like $expirtation to "" or to 1
and expire to ""

but it seams nothing work on wordpress
i even try to call wp_clear_auth_cookie() function onunload event but its not working

what i should to do for removing cookies after browser/tab closed ?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about wordpress but in php, if you set expire time to 0, cookie will destroy after **browser close** (not tab close).
So try to set

```
$expirtation = 0;
```

Comment: i already did that but its not possible for user see behind login pages,

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are usualy used for this. According to Wikipedia, when no expiration date is set, a cookie is cleared when the user closes the browser.

The cookie setter can specify a deletion date, in which case the cookie will be removed on that date. If the cookie setter does not specify a date, the cookie is removed once the user quits his or her browser.

For more [Clear cookies on browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close)