# how to end session or logout a user on browser close MVC ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have designed a MVC Form and would like to end the session when user closes the browser and if re-open the browser, then has to log in again!

I don't know if I have to end session or clear cookies and if so, how should i do it. Will you help me to find my answer...

Thank you!

Comment: There is no fool proof way to determine if someone closed a browser or not.  Also, logins are handled via cookie not session state.  Here is an example thread on a similar subject - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close

Comment: @Tommy thank you for your answer, how and where should i clear the cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

```html
<body onload="SetCookie()" onunload="del_cookie()">
```

source [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldelck.htm)

try modify it yourself

Comment: Thank you very much, but This is not webform and I'm using MVC! where should I put the body onload on MVC?

Comment: Sorry for answering you late. There is javascript, you can put in in your web page aspx.
`<html>
<script>
function del_cookie(name) { document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;'; }
</script>
<body onload="SetCookie()" onunload="del_cookie()">
//your content//
</body>
</html>`

Comment: It's really cool solution, but also works on tab close. So if you are working on multiple tabs it will terminate session for all of them.

Comment: Link is broken. Found it on WaybackMachine, here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130424221916/http://javascript.about.com/library/bldelck.htm

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **In-Proc** Session Mode, in that case you can get Session Timeout Event in the global.asax file. So if you are creating Cookies and other user specific stubs , you can clean those thing using this event.

**In Global.asax.cs**

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Clean-up Code
}
```

In case of **Out-Proc** Mode you will never get Session timeout event.

As Tommy said that there is no fool proof way to determine if someone closed a browser, **But you can do it by Jquery. You need to ping your server at specific time intervals. So when you stop getting anything from the client after specific time duration , you can perform cleaning operation (Same like session timeout)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try .
On browser close or page onload event delete the cookies from javascript or
on browser close event (or page unload event) make a call on server and CLear the session on server.