# Clear cookies on closing browser in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

i am using php codeigniter for building relatively large application where i have to give different log in options for different level of users. And i have done with pretty much everything. I want to clear all cookies and session when the user closes the browser. How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a very basic session set up within the /application/config/config.php file. The variable to be set is

`$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;`

You should however try to [RT(F)M.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

[image]

Comment: acc to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close?rq=1,  it should clear everything by itself, but if the user closes the browser without logging off and if he reopens the browser it directly redirects to loging-success page instead of asking to loging. Why is this so

Comment: Am I missing something? That is for a framework / program written in c# In CodeIgniter when you set sess_expire_on_close to TRUE your entire session when the browser window is closed is destroyed which means your users will have to login.

Comment: Hey, thanks ll try that. i meant these text, " The cookie setter can specify a deletion date, in which case the cookie will be removed on that date. If the cookie setter does not specify a date, the cookie is removed once the user quits his or her browser. " and "Sessions are usualy used for this. According to Wikipedia, when no expiration date is set, a cookie is cleared when the user closes the browser." in that C# ans. anyway, ll try out in php