# Is it possible to clear all cookie at the time one closing browser/browser tab. In asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to clear all cookies when exiting browser.  The purpose of doing this is so that when someone visits this page again after exiting once, the user can have a fresh start.  I'm developing my site in asp.net c#

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close

Comment: is this a user who wants to programmatically delete all cookies on browser close, or a website for which the cookies are deleted on session end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want session cookies. That's pretty simple - just don't specify an expiry date when setting that cookie. This way it will be deleted when the browser closes. Note however that it's when the *browser* closes, not the tab. Closing the tab without closing the browser will keep the cookies until the browser is closed. If the tab is re-opened without closing the browser, the cookies will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by client side code also.

On page load event, set cookie value with empty string

> document.cookie = ' '

Comment: This will cause a page refresh to reset the cookies too.