# How to cancel/unsubscribe all pending HTTP requests in Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

How to cancel/abort all pending HTTP requests in angular 4+.

There is an `unsubscribe` method to cancel HTTP Requests but how to cancel all pending requests all at once.

Especially while route change.

There is one thing I did

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

but how to achieve this globally

Any Ideas?

Comment: make use of interceptors and use timeout

Comment: yeah. Interceptors. I forgot that I'll look into it

Comment: did interceptors not help @SibiRaj

Comment: nope. I tried. but nothing seems to help. I can have time out but unable to use them with routes. did you get anything?

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/6184203

Comment: Do you mean all outstanding requests across the application or across some service?

Comment: yes, @AluanHaddad. Across the application.

Comment: @SibiRaj that is only possible if you aggregate all subscriptions in an application scoped data structure. Interceptors have been suggested and they could accomplish this by writing to such a structure. You can also wrap `Http` in a service which delegates to it, derive from it, or monkey patch it.

Comment: Instead of using `onDestroy`, would suggest to use `CanDeactivateGuard` specific for route change.

Answer (score 99):

Checkout the [`takeUntil()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) operator from RxJS to globally drop your subscriptions :

**- RxJS 6+ (using the `pipe` syntax)**

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class YourComponent {
   protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   [...]

   public httpGet(): void {
      this.http.get()
          .pipe( takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) )
          .subscribe( (data) => { ... });
   }

   public ngOnDestroy(): void {
       // This aborts all HTTP requests.
       this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
       // This completes the subject properlly.
       this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
   }
}
```

**- RxJS < 6**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil'

export class YourComponent {
   protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   [...]

   public httpGet(): void {
      this.http.get()
         .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
         .subscribe( (data) => { ... })
   }

   public ngOnDestroy(): void {
       this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
       this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
   }
}
```

You can basically emit an event on your unsubscribe `Subject` using `next()` everytime you want to complete a bunch of streams. It is also good practice to  unsubscribe to active Observables as the component is destroyed, to avoid memory leaks.

Worth reading :

- [Avoiding take until leaks](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef)
- [A great answer from seangwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription/41177163#41177163)

Comment: Check seangwright's very complete answer on the subject ;) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/7152435

Hope that it helps !

Comment: Don't forget to import takeUntil from RxJs, import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

Answer (score 75):

You can create an interceptor to apply `takeUntil` operator to every request. Then on route change you will emit event that will cancel all pending requests.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) { }

  intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(takeUntil(this.httpCancelService.onCancelPendingRequests()))
  }
}
```

Helper service.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelService {
  private cancelPendingRequests$ = new Subject<void>()

  constructor() { }

  /** Cancels all pending Http requests. */
  public cancelPendingRequests() {
    this.cancelPendingRequests$.next()
  }

  public onCancelPendingRequests() {
    return this.cancelPendingRequests$.asObservable()
  }

}
```

Hook on route changes somewhere in your app (e.g. onInit in appComponent).

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
    this.httpCancelService.cancelPendingRequests()
  }
})
```

And last but not least, register the interceptor to your app.module.ts:

```
  import { HttpCancelInterceptor } from 'path/to/http-cancel.interceptor';
  import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

  @NgModule({
    [...]
    providers: [
      {
        multi: true,
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HttpCancelInterceptor
      }
    ],
    [...]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I think this is the best way

Comment: this seems great but it's forgetting to complete the subject to close it

Comment: This approach is very useful to cancel every pending http request when route changes. I guess, to cancel other subscription(s), we still need to cancel those request separately.

Comment: @hbthanki Yes you need to cancel other requests manually. As unsubscribing everything can be annoying, I usually have a class that implements onDestroy and my components extend this class (I call it Destroyable). It has a public Subject which emits and completes on destroy. My components then have a takeUntil(this.destroyed$) on every observable. So this approach cancels all pending observables when you destroy the component.

Comment: @Logus I didn't close it deliberately because the service lives through the entire time of the app existence and closing the stream would not free any resources anyway. If the subject completed then you would need to create the new one over and over. And when would it create? Who would have this responsibility? It would just make the code more complicated and I'm afraid it would add no value. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. I just wanted to add 'next.handle(req).takeUntil()' won't work.(It didn't worked for me using angular 7 and rxjs version 6.3.3). I used next.handle(req).pipe(takeUntil()) instead.

Comment: @AdnanSheikh yes you're right. When I was writing the answer, the current rxjs did not have pipes yet. Operators were just chainable after each other. In the newest version it is written with pipe (just as you mentioned). Maybe I should update the answer to reflect new rxjs api. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: How to handle the case with duplicate HTTP request? I have an endpoint to upload large file. I want to cancel the pending upload request if new request is created before earlier one is completed.

Comment: @AnujTBE well if you wanted to use the solution above, then you would just call cancelPendingRequests() right before you call the upload (so you kill any existing requests) - but that could also kill other requests you may want to keep. Or you could modify the code and add parameter (e.g. url string) to the cancelPendingRequests method and then filter the observable inside onCancelPendingRequests method, so only the request with that url would get interrupted. But I suggest you look into switchMap operator and how to cancel requests with it stackoverflow.com/questions/56958362/

Comment: Instead of 'event instanceof ActivationEnd' would it make sense to use 'event instanceof NavigationStart' instead so as to abort the http calls a bit sooner?

Comment: What a neat way! Thanks mate

Comment: BEST COPY/PASTE CODE EVER :) n1

Comment: I like this but how do you avoid cancelling requests that are being made on the main app.component?

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to manually unsubscribe all subscriptions, then you can do this:

```
export function AutoUnsubscribe(constructor) {

  const original = constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy;

  constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function() {
    for (const prop in this) {
      if (prop) {
        const property = this[prop];
        if (property && (typeof property.unsubscribe === 'function')) {
          property.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
    }

    if (original && typeof original === 'function') {
      original.apply(this, arguments)
    };
  };

}
```

Then you can use it as decorator in your component

```
@AutoUnsubscribe
export class YourComponent  {
}
```

but you still need to store subscriptions as component properties.
And when you navigating out of component, AutoUnsubscribe function will occurs.

Comment: I like this idea. Might I suggest you make it more robust by handling components which have arrays of subscriptions (not uncommon)?. E.g. `(Array.isArray(property) ? property : [property]).filter(property => isFunction(property.unsubscribe)).forEach(property => property.unsubscribe()));`.

Comment: This is good idea, but need to optimize it, because if you have arrays of big data, then filter will search each element, and it may be a little bit slow. May be we can check only first element of array and if its subsctiption then we can assume that all array is subscriptions elements.

Comment: you could do that but I doubt it's going to be a significant performance impact.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not convinced of the need for the functionality requested, but you can accomplish this, cancelling all outstanding requests whenever and wherever you wish by wrapping the framework's http service and delegating to it.

However, when we go about implementing this service, a problem quickly becomes apparent. On the one hand, we would like to avoid changing existing code, including third party code, which leverages the stock Angular http client. On the other hand, we would like to avoid implementation inheritance.

To get the best of both worlds we can *implement* the Angular `Http` service with our wrapper. Existing code will continue to work without changes (provided said code does not do anything stupid like use `http instanceof Http`).

```
import {Http, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';



export default interface CancellationAwareHttpClient extends Http { }

export default class CancellationAwareHttpClient {
  constructor(private wrapped: Http) {
    const delegatedMethods: Array<keyof Http> = [
      'get', 'post', 'put', 'delete',
      'patch', 'head', 'options'
    ];
    for (const key of delegatedMethods) {
      this[key] = wrapped[key].bind(wrapped);
    }
  }

  cancelOutstandingRequests() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
    this.subscriptions = [];
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
    const subscription = this.wrapped.request(url, options);
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
    return subscription;
  }

  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
}
```

Note that the `interface` and `class` declarations for `CancellationAwareHttpClient` are merged. In this way, our class *implements* `Http` by virtue of the `interface` declaration's `extends` clause.

Now we will provide our service

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

import CancellationAwareHttpClient from 'app/services/cancellation-aware-http-client';

let cancellationAwareClient: CancellationAwareHttpClient;

const httpProvider = {
  provide: Http,
  deps: [ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions],
  useFactory: function (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    if (!cancellationAwareClient) {
      const wrapped = new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
      cancellationAwareClient = new CancellationAwareHttpClient(wrappedHttp);
    }
    return cancellationAwareClient;
  }
};

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    // provide our service as `Http`, replacing the stock provider
    httpProvider,
    // provide the same instance of our service as `CancellationAwareHttpClient`
    // for those wanting access to `cancelOutstandingRequests`
    {...httpProvider, provide: CancellationAwareHttpClient}
  ]
}) export class SomeModule {}
```

Note how we override the existing framework provided service. We use a factory to create our instance and do not add any decorators for DI to the wrapper itself in order to avoid a cycle in the injector.

Comment: I wanted to achieve that because even when I navigate through pages. the HTTP requests that are pending does not get canceled.  I have to use destroy subscription on every page. I thought why not do it globally i.e., during a route change cancel all pending HTTP requests.

Comment: correct me If what I was thinking to achieve is wrong :)

Comment: @SibiRaj I don't think it's wrong :) just be careful when you introduce global state. The nice thing about this approach is that you can experiment with it without changing any of the services or components that use `Http`.

Comment: Hi @AluanHaddad, where did you get `wrappedHttp` from? Your comment doesn't clarify this. Can you please share with us more details about? Thx

Comment: @Sibiraj I instantiated it directly. It is in the example but the code may need minor adjustments to work in angular 6/7

Answer (score 4):

`ngOnDestroy` callback is typically used for any custom cleanup that needs to occur when the instance is destroyed.

where do you want to cancel your request?

maybe if you want cancel your requests on browser close there is creative idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh)

Comment: I wanted to cancel request on route change

Comment: you should call ngOnDestroy() on components that may be router-outlet

Comment: so I should do on all components individually?

Comment: only component that may place on router-outlet. because when router-outlet changes "ngOnDestroy()" got called.

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe();
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this will not cancel pending requests.

Comment: yes, I want to cancel all at once. i.e, while route change

Answer (score 1):

```
    //This is the example of cancelling the get request once you leave the TestComponent.

    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html'
    })
    export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

      request: any;
someList: any;

      constructor( private _someService: SomeService) {

      }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getList();
      }

      ngOnDestroy(){
        this.request.unsubscribe(); // To cancel the get request.
      }

      getList() {
        this.request= this._someService.getAll()
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.someList= response;
          }, (error) => {
            console.log("Error fetching List", error);
          })
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding something to @Bladito answer which is almost perfect.

Actually, the HttpCancelService stack is perfect, but the probleme is where it's called. Calling this on navigation end may cause problems if you have child routes.

So I made an abstract container component which call the HttpCancelService when it's destroyed. That way I can manage when I want to cut any Http Cancelling request with more fine grain.

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpCancelService } from '../../services/http-cancel-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-abstract-container',
  template: `
    ABSTRACT COMPONENT
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./abstract-container.component.scss']
})
export class AbstractContainerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(protected readonly httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.httpCancelService.cancelPendingRequests();
  }
}
```

And there it's a concrete component extending the abstract component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractContainerComponent } from '../../../shared/components/abstract-container/abstract-container.component';
import { HttpCancelService } from '../../../shared/services/http-cancel-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-concrete-container',
  templateUrl: '.some-concrete-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-concrete-container.component.scss']
})
export class SomeConcreteContainerComponent extends AbstractContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(protected readonly httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) {
    super(httpCancelService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to cancel requests on route change level because one will lose granularity.

For instance, maybe you want to cancel a request on one component and not on another because it's not going to destory. Most importantly, what about background requests? It will be very trickey to debug why some requests have randomly been cancelled.

But its generally a good idea to cancel `get` requests whose component is going to destroy, **regardless of route change**.

---

### Unsubscribing from observables on destroy

If you want to make your life easy then use [until-destroy](https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy). It will automatically unsubscribe all observables when your component is going going to be destroyed (`ngOnDestroy`).
It's granule enough and more general (not just HttpRequests but all `observables` will been unsubscribed from)

```
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
     
@UntilDestroy()
@Component({})
export class InboxComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    interval(1000)
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom Http Service (using HttpClient) which maintains a list of pending requests. Whenever you fire a http us this custom service instead of Http/HttpClient,now push the subscriptions to a list and on return of the response pop that subscription out. Using this you will have all the incomplete subscriptions in a list.

Now in the same custom service Inject router in the constructor and subscribe on it to get the route change events. Now whenever this observable emits, all you need to do is to unsubscribe all the subscriptions present in the list and pop all the elements from it.

If you need code snippet, do mention in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple, tested, and working example

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "../services/data.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"],
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild("image") image: ElementRef;
  loading = false;
  subscriptions = [];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  start() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.image.nativeElement.classList.add("animate");
    const subscription = this.dataService
      .paymentRequest()

      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.image.nativeElement.classList.remove("animate");
          this.loading = false;
          console.log(data);
        },
        (error) => this.start()
      );
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
  }

  stop() {
    this.loading = false;
    this.image.nativeElement.classList.remove("animate");
    this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
    this.subscriptions = [];
    // This completes the subject properlly.
  }
}
```