# How to cancel HttpRequests when changing a component

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular5, angular-http-interceptors

I'm developping an application with angular 5.

I need to stop all http queries when changing/detroyiog components.

example : i open ListUsersComponent, a httpquery is started to get the list of users, before that query is finished i opened ListAdminsComponent. so in network (browser) i have the query getting the list of users query still pending.

I want to stop it when i destroy ListUsersComponent.

> how stop queries when i change the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution :

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) { }

  intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    return next.handle(req).takeUntil(this.httpCancelService.onCancelPendingRequests())
  }
}
```

CancelService

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpCancelService {
  private cancelPendingRequests$ = new Subject<void>()

  constructor() { }

  /** Cancels all pending Http requests. */
  public cancelPendingRequests() {
    this.cancelPendingRequests$.next()
  }

  public onCancelPendingRequests() {
    return this.cancelPendingRequests$.asObservable()
  }

}
```

link :
[cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068908/how-to-cancel-unsubscribe-all-pending-http-requests-angular-4/49797920#49797920)