# Discard all pending HTTP requests with Ionic

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, ionic-framework

My Ionic app triggers several concurrent HTTP requests. If one of them fails, an error page is stacked above the navcontroller. In such error state I'd like to ignore all other requests so that they can't lead to leave the error page since they might cause stacking new pages.

Is there a "discard all pending HTTP requests" option for Ionic version 3.20.0?

Comment: IONIC Version??

Comment: Version 3.20.0 Post updated, @SangwinGawande

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068908/how-to-cancel-unsubscribe-all-pending-http-requests-angular-4