# How to cancel requests incase of triggering them using forkJoin Rxjs , Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a set of 6 http get requests which I have to make irrespective of their sequence on a button click.I am using `forkJoin` for that purpose

```
<button click="getData()">Get Data</button>


getData(){

  const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  const obs = ids.map(id => this.http.get('<my url>/' + id)

  forkJoin(...obs).subscribe(res => console.log(res));

}
```

If a user clicks on the button multiple time, is there a way I could cancel previous uncompleted requests and only make new fresh calls to the backend ?

I did some research and understood switchMap operator helps in cancelling requests but I am not sure how I would be using it here.

Please help

Comment: Can't you just disable the button until the old request are done?

Comment: Have you thought about disabling the button while the request is in-progress?

Comment: @Tim567 Yes that can be done but  wanted to know how I can cancel previously hit request and trigger new calls

Comment: The above code is just to demonstrate my problem, its actually a carousel with next and previous button, I cannot disable next button in the carousel when user clicks on it and wait un till all 6 requests are completed,

Comment: posted an answer below.

Comment: See answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068908/how-to-cancel-unsubscribe-all-pending-http-requests-angular-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public subscription: Subscription;

getData(){

  const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  const obs = ids.map(id => this.http.get('<my url>/' + id)

  if(this.subscription){
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  this.subscription = forkJoin(...obs).subscribe(res =>console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: what is this.process ?

Comment: This is a good idea. But doesn't this cancel the existing requests and send a new one on keypress, instead of cancelling the new and keeping the old one?

Comment: he said he wanted to discard old request and only cater new one in the question, if he wanted old one, i would have given him solution of exhaustmap.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the operator you are looking for is [ExhaustMap](http://ExhaustMap)

The older version of ExhaustMap is the flatMapFirst() operator which propagates data from the first mapped observable, and it only goes to the next when it finishes discarding all the other observables before finishing.

Comment: it would be great if you could help me with how to use it with forkJoin

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/9863484) states:

Most of the jQuery Ajax methods return an `XMLHttpRequest` (or the equivalent) object, so you can just use `abort()`.

```php
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    success: function(msg){
       alert("Done");
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: This is a traditonal javascript way to abort a request, I am more looking for a rxjs way, anyway thanks for answering :)