# How to write window closing event handler in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to write window closing event handler in `Angular 2`, by that I mean closing not refreshing.

So I can't use `window.onBeforeunLoad();`

Comment: I think not any way to find differentiate browser closed or refresh. both are same in term of programming

Comment: Use host listeners for such a scope.

Comment: its always better to give some thing you have tried , people her are not going to just solve them for you

Comment: You can refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh however it's not in `typescript` but you might get some idea or logic.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this :

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But it will also get fired on window refresh. But I don't want that.