# Can we handle browser close event instead of 'beforeunload'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

how to handle browser close event? I tried using 'beforeunload' event which is also firing on page refresh, any solution?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {

        var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    };
```

Comment: can you please share the code snippet?

Comment: I've updated the question, please take a look

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh

Comment: What does *handle* mean here? What do you want to do with/in this event?

Comment: on browser close, I want to clear server sessions

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, you can google it first :)