# How to detect if the browser window is closing (not reload, only close) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to call a function that logsout users from the system when the browser's window is closing.

I found a function `window.onbeforeunload` but this also gets called when you reload the browser and I dont want the user to be logged out when he reloads the browser. I need to do it once the browser window is closed.

Is this even feasible?

Comment: theres no way, one thing you could do is logout on each close (`onbeforeunload`) and relogin using cookies. Create the cookie without a expiry date, then it will be deleted if the browser gets closed.

Comment: This should help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: how can I detect if there is been no activity on browser for sometime or 5 min?

Answer (score -1):

From [Firefox Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fbeforeunload)

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirm_message = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirm_message ; 
  return confirm_message ;                      
});
```

This example working on all browsers

Comment: it calls whether you reload or close

Comment: Yes because if you reload the page all scripts will first unload and then again reload

Comment: @Ray i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34329402/11988937) will help you