# Remove cookie when browser close in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

How do I remove or delete cookies when users close the browser? I have the code here using cookie-parser in NodeJS with the maxAge property which I do not know what value should I put in order to delete the cookie when users close the browser. I believe Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated.

res.cookie('authcookie',accessToken,{maxAge:???,httpOnly:true})

Comment: Duplicate of [Clear cookies on browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783302/clear-cookies-on-browser-close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no `Expires` or `Max-Age` parameter set for the cookie, then the browser will treat is as a "session cookie" and will not store the cookie beyond the current browsing session (typically kept only in memory).  So, when the browser is closed, the cookie will be gone.

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver.